# mat-selection-list with an object , is it possible?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-list

I have been looking at the mat-selection-list found in the material.angular.io documentation at material.angular.io/components/list/overview

I would like to use a array of objects instead of using a string array .
The documentation has

```
 typesOfShoes: string[] = ['Falta passar fio', 'Peça oxidada'];
```

And this seems to work but my object, below, doesn't work. What I am doing wrong? or is this not possible?

```
errorList = [
    { id: 1234, type: 'A1', description: 'dsfdsfdfgdgdgfio', selected:false },
    { id: 4567, type: 'C6', description: 'Pesdffsdça sdfsd', selected:false },
    { id: 7890, type: 'A5', description: 'sdfdsfc', selected:false }
];

<mat-selection-list #errorList class="area-block ">
    <mat-list-option *ngFor="let err of errorList " style="color: #000000;">
        {{err.type}}           
    </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>

<p style="color: #000000;" class="area-block">
    Options selected: {{errorList.selectedOptions.selected.length}}
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
<mat-selection-list #book [multiple]="false">
  <mat-list-option *ngFor="let book of books" [value]="book">
    {{ book.name }}
  </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

Notice: I set #book, maybe you should set #err instead of #errorList

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `[value]`:

```
<mat-selection-list #errorList class="area-block">
   <mat-list-option *ngFor="let err of errorList" [value]="err" style="color: #000000;">
      {{err.type}}
   </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

**Edit:**

Not sure, what exactly is not working, but if you want to show just number of items selected, then the another **answer by @Srinivasan Sekar** should help which states "naming conflict" you have `#errorList` and `errorList` array of your objects, and you need to change. But if you want to get data from the selected field, then use `[value]`. For multiple selection: you need to create method and keep adding the selected values to your array for your use. All depends on your user case.

The [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mn-angular-material-select-multi) might cover your all user cases.

Comment: [value]="err.id" ??

Comment: @SrinivasanSekar It depends what the OP needs to bind. Not sure what exactly is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Name conflict is the issue,just change `#errorList` to `#errorlist` and `errorList.selectedOptions.selected.length` to `errorlist.selectedOptions.selected.length`

```
<mat-selection-list #errorlist class="area-block ">
        <mat-list-option *ngFor="let err of errorList " style="color: #000000;">
       {{err.type}}

            </mat-list-option>
          </mat-selection-list>

          <p  style="color: #000000;" class="area-block ">
              Options selected: {{errorlist.selectedOptions.selected.length}}
            </p>
```